# What is the best way to handle form inputs state in a controlled REACT component?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I have a basic form in React component. 
For example :

```
export default class SimpleForm extends Component {

_isMounted = false;

state = {
    firstName:'',
    lastName : ''
};

changeState(data){
    this.setState(data);
}

handleInput(event){
    this.changeState({
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
}
render(){
    const {
        firstName,
        lastName
    } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="">
            <Form>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="firstName" sm={3}>First Name</Label>
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <Input  type="text" value={firstName} onChange={(event)=>{this.handleInput(event)}} name="firstName" id="firstName" className="input-lg" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="lastName" sm={3}>Last Name</Label>
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <Input  type="text" value={lastName} onChange={(event)=>{this.handleInput(event)}} name="lastName" id="lastName" className="input-lg" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

My concern here is each time we change an input field, the state changes. This is definitely the standard approach. I am not sure if this is the only approach to handle state. With this approach the component re renders for every character change. Isn't this expensive?
If we have lots of inputs, and lets say we need to calculate character count on some of the input fields then the count value needs some time to appear obviously because of the heavy re rendering.

Comment: "Isn't this expensive?" Measure it. Is the performance a problem for your particular app? "the count value needs some time to appear" – is it actually being slow for you?

Comment: @AKX well for the case of count value it was a bit slow when the input was mixed in a single component with other heavy components so i have to move it out to a child component. I was hoping if there are other techniques to capture form inputs in a state. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, re-rendering can be expensive.

You could avoid re-renders with uncontrolled inputs: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

I would recommand to prefer uncontrolled inputs and only use controlled inputs if some values in your form depends on each others